# Mongoose multiple models for same connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to use models with single mongoose.connect().

I have simple database in MongoDB like this

```
ProjectDB
|_ tableA
|_ tableB
```

And I have simple server in NodeJs

```
ProjectFolder
|-> server.js
|-> /db
    |-> mongooseDb.js
    |-> /models
       |-> tableA.js
       |-> tableB.js
```

**mongooseDb.js**
*Connect database and create single instance*

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
function Connect(){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        mongoose.connect(connectionString, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})
        .then((res)=>{
            global.mongoose=mongoose;
            resolve("Connection Successfull");
        })
        .catch((e)=>{reject(e);})
    })
}
module.exports={
    Connect
}
```

**server.js** *Create server and listen port*

```
var express = require("express");
var db=require("./db/mongooseDb");
var tableA=require("./db/models/tableA");
const app = express();
db.Connect()
.then((res)=>{
    app.listen(port, () => console.log("Server Ready On port " + port));
    tableA.Save({ name: 'John' });
})
.catch((err)=>{})
```

**tableA.js** *Model for tableA*

```
class tableA{
  constructor(){
    this.tableModel=global.mongoose.model('tableA', { name: String });
  } 
  Save(data){
    this.tableModel.create(data)
    .then((res)=>{console.log(res)})
    .catch((err)=>{console.log(err)})
  }
}  
const _tableA = new tableA();
module.exports={
  _tableA
}
```

When I run the code I get an error.

> this.tableModel=global.mongoose.model('tableA', { name: String }); 
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'model' of undefined

- Do I have to create a separate connection object for each model?
- Can I share same connection object for multiple models? (tableA, tableB)
- If models share same connection object, does it cause a problem in their use?

Answer (score 1):

After debugs and more researches, I noticed **require("mongoose")** returns same instance of object. So I change the code like this.

**tableA.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
class tableA{
  constructor(){
    this.tableModel=mongoose.model('tableA', { name: String });
  } 
  Save(data){
    this.tableModel.create(data)
    .then((res)=>{console.log(res)})
    .catch((err)=>{console.log(err)})
  }
}  
const _tableA = new tableA();
module.exports={
  _tableA
}
```